# How to get all category ids of a product in prestashop ? (including sub category of sub category's)

Tags: prestashop

I am trying to get all category ids associated to product.
that includes `category's sub category,sub category' sub category`.

i have tried

```
print_r($prestashopProductClass->getAllChildren()); exit;
```

Is their any way that we can get it ?

Answer (score 0):

You this `Product::getProductCategoriesFull(your_product_id)` in your controller or class.
Also, you can use it in your tpl file like that  `{foreach from=Product::getProductCategoriesFull(Tools::getValue('id_product')) item=cat} {/foreach}`

Comment: Is their any way to get sub categories of a selected category ?

Comment: Product::getProductCategoriesFull(your_product_id) -> this does not return all categories